# Password special character validation

Tags: delphi

I want my code to check if what's written in an edit box contains special characters. It is doing that, but it checks every single char one by one if a special character is found in the Array. It will show a message ('Password must...') if the first letter/char is not a special character, and carries on checking if the other letters are a special character until it reaches the end of what is written in the edit box, even though it has found a special character in maybe the third char, for example.

```
for Number := 1 to Length(s) do
begin
  if Position(s[Number],Array) > 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Success');
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Password must contain at least one special character');
  end;   
end;
```

Comment: Read up on System.Continue and System.Break. (Basic Pascal knowledge)

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Break

Comment: Why use Break, when repeat or while loops do the trick more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the loop if a "special char" is found. You can use `Break` for that. You also need to remember whether such a character was found or not, and then act on that result after the loop is finished.

Try something more like this instead.

```
var
  hasSpecialChar: Boolean;
...
hasSpecialChar := False;
for Number := 1 to Length(s) do
begin
  if Position(s[Number],Array) > 0 then
  begin
    hasSpecialChar := True;
    Break;
  end;
end;
if hasSpecialChar then
  ShowMessage('Success') 
else
  ShowMessage('Password must contain at least one special character');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use regular expression that will make your life way more easy
this example should do the trick
it return a string with all the used char that arent letters or number

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    Regex: TPerlRegEx;
    sApp: string;
    begin

      regex:= TPerlRegEX.Create;

      try

        Regex.RegEx := '[^a-zA-Z0-9]';// match every character that isn't in a --> z A --> Z 0 --9


        Regex.State := [preNotEmpty];
        regex.Options := [preNoAutoCapture];

        Regex.Subject := edit1.Text;

        sapp := '';

        if Regex.Match then
        begin

          repeat

            sapp := sapp + regex.MatchedText;

          until not Regex.MatchAgain;

        end;

      finally
        Regex.Free;
      end;

      ShowMessage(sapp);

    end;
```

i Have used delphi 11 and System.RegularExpressionsCore
but the trick is made by this regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` then you can use
the library that you prefer
try it out!

Comment: ah and obviously in the end
  if trim(sapp) = '' then
    showmessage('No special characters!');